# Is it mathematically known what the complexity limit (and class) of a pattern to learn is, for a given machine learning algorithm?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, complexity, ai

Given a learning algorithm such as those used in ChatGPT, can we calculate based on the number of neural network parameters what the largest “pattern” the algorithm could learn would be (based on some way of quantifying “size of pattern”)?

For example, if a neural network approximately is a decision tree, could we prove that it would be incapable of “learning” something (emulating a certain behavior, giving outputs we judge as correct given inputs) if we know that the attempt to explicate that thing in terms of rules would give rise to a rule set which is, combinatorially, of a greater magnitude than the algorithm can model?

Not just regarding size, but also *class*: I believe in set theory, we know that there are mathematical forms which are inexpressible within a certain kind of mathematical system. I think examples of this might be unprovable truths, transcendental numbers, inaccessible cardinals, etc. Can we prove that there is some domain of cognition that ChatGPT in its current form can not do, because we know that the mathematical basis (of rational functions) cannot do certain mathematical things? (I don’t know if this is a good example but I was thinking about how certain axioms added to ZFC allow it to prove or express certain ideas.)

I wish I knew all the mathematics of what I said above more rigorously, so I could express these questions better. Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: For classifiers you may want to look into the VC dimension. Chat GPT is not a classifier. Also even if it was, it's simply far too complex to calculate an exact VC dimension for. What we know about ChatGPT's limitations is almost entirely based on just empirically observing what it does.

Comment: We can say that ChatGPT has a limited memory and therefore cannot solve computational problems that require more memory than that. However, Chat GPT has a lot of memory, so this is not really very constraining on its capabilities.

Comment: I don't really understand negative and close votes here. Given that there is theory such as VC dimension as mentioned, it is a very legitimate question to what extent such results imply limits on machine learning in general. It would also be interesting to elaborate why or why not existing theory applies to what we can interpret as "learning" of ChatGPT and the like, and if not, whether such theory would be in principle possible.

Comment: @causative Is "classifier" a description of what it IS or what it is USED FOR?

Comment: I’m open to suggested edits for this question